# I have more new users than new sessions in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have nearly 250 more new users than new sessions. My understanding is that these two metrics should be identical, and that one reason users might be higher than sessions (in general) is a use case where an event fires and a user leaves before a page view has had a chance to fire.

Are there other reasons this might happen for new users, specifically?

If I configure a session-level advanced segment on the user explorer where:

1. Pageviews = 0 and
2. User Type = New Visitor

I only get 8 users. Oddly:

- One user's session has just one events with zero page views (yay!).
- One user's session has an event and a page view (*what?!*).
- The remaining six have *no hits at all* (*double what?!*).

How might this happen?